# How long does Modmyi take to post an app on Cydia?

Tags: cydia

I've submitted my app to be hosted by Modmyi and it was accepted yesterday. The email said it should be live in Cydia within 3-4 hours if it isn't already, but that was 5pm yesterday and it's not live yet. I don't know if I should keep waiting or email their support. If anyone has used Modmyi before, how long did it take for your app to go live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email support or hit up @mmirepo. The package most likely was lost or not uploaded correctly - it should be live within 2 hours of receiving that acceptance email.